# Wordpress: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Settings::printLinks()

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the error I get when I load any of my sites but one:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Settings::printLinks() in /home/admin/server/index.php on line 87 
Call Stack: 0.0001 644544 1. {main}() /home/admin/server/index.php:0
```

The error showed about 2 hours ago caused by no obvious reasons... nothing has been moderated to cause it.

Comment: No obvious reason!? It's because your code can't find the `printLinks()` static method from `Settings` anywhere........ Read the error and google "Call to undefined method", Jesus!

Comment: You need to learn how to [READ and debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) error messages. Everything you needed to solve the problem was in the error message. Where have you defined settings class and printLinks method in all your other sites?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue on my wordpress site from yesterday. And yes hakerke, when I googled it, I found that thousands of wordpress sites are facing the same problem. Gaurang, please check your source if there's any link of 'Casino' site.

Comment: @Jimbo I just received this error, I am working on WP right now.. this is really an issue

Comment: @Mr.Alien You use wordpress? `$opinion--;` !!!!

Comment: @Jimbo Nah, I just work at a company where they use wordpress...

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's not optional? Opinion restored :)

Comment: @Jimbo nah ;) I don't know what is causing this, will show you the screen, give me a moment

Comment: http://s22.postimg.org/f3jywbnrl/Untitled.png

Comment: From what I've seen, this was an error displayed from an SEO hack someone wrote recently. Now this hack is silent, see affected web sites http://www.dceh.org/about/staff/ and http://jbsigndepot.com/ for example - yesterday they had an error message displayed, today they do not, they only include the hidden forex-brokers, online casino links, in source code, which are fetched from http://jqury.net/?1. I'm guessing whatever error the hacker had in their code, they fixed so that sites would not realize they are linking to spammy sites in their html source.

Comment: It could be http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108539

Answer (score 2):

It happened yesterday to thousand (or more?) of wordpress users.
The mainly reasons are plugins, so disable them all.
If it still shows, then its probably caused by your theme
you can change it or upload it on another blog just to be sure

Comment: Almost everyone is blaming the plugins, but how is possible that these plugins suddenly started giving error on a same day all over the world. I would like to tell here that yesterday I received emails from my site's firewall that some suspicious activities have been detected and blocked. Today there is the same error on my site and someone has inserted links of "casino" sites which I'm still unable to remove.

Comment: @Harshad Manjre How to solved this problem?

Comment: @Gaurang P If I knew it I would have answered it. I want to know if your source has the casino sites' links.

Comment: My one Plugin in problem. Solved it problem, thanks

Comment: @GaurangP what plugin?

Comment: @HarshadManjre Could you post the relevant parts of those firewall logs? Or at least send them to security@wordpress.org for analysis? Looks like this is affecting many sites now.

Comment: This was the mail I got from my firewall - TYPE: Found Basic DoS Attacks
DETECTED ATTACK VALUE: dDos Attack
ACTION: Blocked
LOGTIME: 2013-07-30 01:36:35
FROM IP: http://whois.domaintools.com/
URI: http://
METHOD:
USERAGENT: N/A
REFERRER: N/A

Answer (score 0):

Problem for me was a popup plugin.

Comment: Which plugin was that?